# DIV whitespace removal. Normal techniques not working

Tags: html, css

I have a "3 block" design I am working on.  The entire design is vertical-align middle.  I am wanting to remove the white space between the divs.

If I set `body{font-size: 0px;}` it looks as it should, then I give each child it's own font size.  But once I give more than one child a size, it reverts back to stage 1.  I'm not overly keen on this method as it means I cannot use em sizing.

I have also tried to comment out after the closing div and before the opening.

```
</div><!--
--><div>
```

But this time, it's not working either; which is puzzling.

The only other two options I can think of is to no close tags which HTML5 supports, but is sloppy and not actually correct or to use negative margins, which again; is incorrect and has problems with certain devices/browsers.

Does anyone have a clean, easy to read solution to this problem?

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    html {
      display: table;
      margin: auto;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #BFBFBF;
      width: 1180px;
    }
    #header {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      width: 1180px;
      height: 165px;
    }
    #content {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
    #footer {
      background-color: #35363A;
      height: 76px;
    }
    .table {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #333333;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #729ea5;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .table th {
      font-size: 12px;
      background-color: #acc8cc;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #729ea5;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .table tr {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .table td {
      font-size: 12px;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #729ea5;
    }
    .table tr:hover {
      background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="index.php">
    <img id="logo" src="./images/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <a href="./index.php">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="./newsletter.php">
        <li>Newsletter</li>
      </a>
      <a href="../users/list.php">
        <li>User List</li>
      </a>
      <a href="./admin/index.php">
        <li>Admin Panel</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>
    <br />
    <h2></h2>
    <br />
    <br />

    <ol>

    </ol>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p class="copyright"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Read [ask]. Create MCVE. ttyl.

Comment: The comment trick you posted is usually a solid solution to this problem. Can you post the code you're working on?

Comment: Please post a code example in your question. Otherwise we're just speculating.

Comment: Question edited to show.

Comment: This image should show, 3 colour blocks with two grey "whitespaces" which I don't want. http://gyazo.com/512b1bf5177494e6eb4010a62e92e678

Comment: `ul {} li {} .copyright {} form {} #newslettercontent {} .table {` is a new way to write css?

Comment: The margin is created by the p- and ul-tags in the containers. When removing that margin, the gap is gone - but that can`t be the answer imho...

Comment: @Huangism Apparently it's the new way to write it, or so Amit thinks as he's the cleaver one whom edited it...

Comment: @DanielMinett I have removed the empty selectors as they serve no purpose in this question and it clusters the view. If you want to add them back, feel free to edit it them back in

Comment: Thanks, I shall leave them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was to add:

```
p, div, ol {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

And the margin is gone (look at the snippet below).

But I'm quite sure you'd like to have a more specific selector as using a `*` selector is not recommended at all.

```css
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    html {
      display: table;
      margin: auto;
    }
    p, div, ol {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #BFBFBF;
      width: 1180px;
    }
    #header {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      width: 1180px;
      height: 165px;
    }
    #logo {} #logout {} #navigation {} ul {} ul li {} ul li:hover {} ol {} .todo {} .wip {} .done {} a {} a:visited {} #content {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
    #footer {
      background-color: #35363A;
      height: 76px;
    }
    ul {} li {} .copyright {} form {} #newslettercontent {} .table {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #333333;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #729ea5;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .table th {
      font-size: 12px;
      background-color: #acc8cc;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #729ea5;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .table tr {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .table td {
      font-size: 12px;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #729ea5;
    }
    .table tr:hover {
      background-color: #ffff99;
    }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="index.php">
    <img id="logo" src="./images/logo.png" />
  </a>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <a href="./index.php">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="./newsletter.php">
        <li>Newsletter</li>
      </a>
      <a href="../users/list.php">
        <li>User List</li>
      </a>
      <a href="./admin/index.php">
        <li>Admin Panel</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>
    <br />
    <h2></h2>
    <br />
    <br />

    <ol>

    </ol>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p class="copyright"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but like you said it's not ideal.  I was hoping for a cleaner way to do it, is that possible?

Comment: The margin is created by the p- and ul-tags in the containers. When removing that margin, the gap is gone - but that can`t be the answer imho...

Comment: Also your `ol` tag has natural margin as well. You just need to reset the natural margins. take a look at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and take what you need. Currently your design is not display inline-block so there is no point doing the comments in between divs

Comment: @Huangism That's the answer I need, can you put it on and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielMinett my friend, this current answer is basically is what i said minus the link. Amit does mention you will need specific selectors. He should edit his answer to be more complete. If he does not and you won't accept this then I will post an answer later

Comment: Setting p margin 0 solved it, I've accepted it but I'd rather do so on one that is actually an answer, not just a solution.  After all, he did feel the need to mess up my questions code...  Thanks again!